# Is there a way to force Deferred Name Resolution even if the table exists when creating a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

When creating a stored procedure in SQL Server, you are allowed to refer to tables which do not exist. But, if the table does exist then any column you refer to in the procedure must exist in that table ([Deferred Name Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686%28SQL.90%29.aspx)).

Is it possible to instruct SQL Server to defer the name resolution of all tables referenced in a procedure irrespective of whether they exist or not? I do want to keep the general syntax checking, so even if it were possible, hacking the stored procedure definition into a system table isn't an option.

I expect my asking to do this might seem a *little bit weird*, so here's some background: I auto generate table definitions and stored procedures from an application written in C# and it's very difficult for me to change the code to order the changes as SQL needs them. My code "guarantees" that the schema is consistent within a transaction, but currently I can't guarantee that the table columns are defined before I define the stored procedure which references them.

Below is a canonical example of the SQL created by the C# which "illustrates" the problem I'm trying to solve.

```
--Say this table already exists.
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    a NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

--My C# code creates something like this
BEGIN TRAN 
GO

--the stored procedure gets generated first.
CREATE PROCEDURE mySproc
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT a,b FROM myTable
END

--then the table update
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD b nvarchar(MAX)

COMMIT TRAN
```

It *is* possible for me to fix this in the C# code, but I'm hoping for a simple "magic" tweak I can pull in the SQL. This will save a **lot** of time for me.

Comment: Can't you just process all schema changes before creating/altering any procedures? Why must the procedure exist before the table is correct?

Comment: I'm pursing that option in the code now. The way the SQL is generated is fairly complicated (that was a simple example) but it's looking like it's not going to be as much as a PITA as I thought.

Comment: You can get around it of course by stuffing your stored procedures full of dynamic SQL - but I can't imagine generating your script to handle schema changes then stored procedures would be all that difficult. There aren't too many any options exposed to dictate how deferred name resolution works. The only proposal on the books that I know of, or at least that I can infer they're interested in entertaining, is actually the other way - making it MORE strict - see http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html).

Comment: Good idea about the dynamic SQL. I've got the same problem for Triggers, Indexes, Views, Sprocs, and Functions. But I've changed the code so that it just makes changes to the Tables, then Indexes, then Triggers, then functions, then sprocs.

Comment: I like sommarskog's suggestions, definitely will help avoid bugs. If they did implement a Strict option, then they could also reevaluate all the "Strict ON" sprocs when there is a table change to see if it breaks existing sprocs - obviously you would need then to have a "logical transaction on DDL" so you can then change the Table and Sprocs as one unit.

Comment: Well you can have a transaction around DDL as well as DML, but the changes still need to take place in the right order. (This is how tools like Red-Gate's SQL Compare do it - they can roll back all their schema mods easily when they come across an error.) There was a more recent question about this, you may want to watch it in case someone comes up with a better answer than mine: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13648/dont-want-to-be-able-creating-stored-procedures-with-incorrect/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

I feel really guilty just typing that, but no, sadly.  That's the first time I've heard of this use case, and it makes perfect sense.  Best to submit a request for it on https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server and your grandchildren will be able to do it. ;-)

Comment: Bleak AND Hilarious lol

Answer (score 7):

Just in case you are still interested, there is a potential workaround you can employ. Here is the updated code, which introduces the `#deferResolution` temporary table to each query in the procedure. Because the temporary table will only exist at runtime, the procedure is able to compile even though the proper columns don't yet exist on `myTable`.

You will even get the same execution plan (no reference to the `#deferResolution` table) for each statement in the procedure due to the way that the query optimizer can prove this `WHERE NOT EXISTS` always evaluates to true.

All that said, this is a terrible hack presented mostly for intellectual interest and there could be an edge case where it breaks down. As Aaron mentions, you would likely be better off making all of your schema changes in the proper order.

```
--Say this table already exists.
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    a NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
GO

--My C# code creates something like this
BEGIN TRAN 
GO

--the sproc gets generated first.
CREATE PROCEDURE mySproc
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #deferResolution (dummy INT NOT NULL)
    SELECT a,b FROM myTable WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #deferResolution WHERE 0=1)
END

--then the table update
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD b nvarchar(MAX)

COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: I am curious if anyone knows why this works. I do appreciate the hack though!