# don't want to be able creating stored procedures with incorrect

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Right now I can execute a CREATE PROCEDURE or an ALTER PROCEDURE script with incorrect table and column references in the MS SQL Server Management Studio and using ADO.NET commands. The scripts run fine, but if I open the created stored procedures on MS SQL Server using Management Studio, then I'll see incorrect tables and columns being highlighted in red. I want to get those errors when creating or altering stored procedures. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't change the way deferred name resolution works. See [this Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=127152), [this Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/260762/add-optional-checks-for-more-robust-development) and also this section on Erland Sommarskog's "SET STRICT_CHECKS ON" proposal: http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html#killDNR