# Invalid column name even after checking if it exists so it should skip the query part

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query

I've got the following query:

```
    IF EXISTS( SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NotificationTableLogRows' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'DestinationAddress') BEGIN  
      UPDATE NotificationTableLogRows
      SET [HandlerID] = m.ID
      FROM [Unicare].dbo.MobileDevices m
      WHERE HandlerID is null 
      AND m.CallNumber = NotificationTableLogRows.DestinationAddress AND NotificationTableLogRows.HandlerTypeID = 2
    END
print 'end'
```

But after running this, I still got the error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'DestinationAddress'.
```

It should however just print **end**

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

Even with:

```
IF 1 = 0 BEGIN
    UPDATE NotificationTableLogRows
    SET [HandlerID] = m.ID
    FROM [Unicare].dbo.MobileDevices m
    WHERE HandlerID is null 
    AND m.CallNumber = NotificationTableLogRows.DestinationAddress AND NotificationTableLogRows.HandlerTypeID = 2
END
```

It produces the same error, the problem seems to be in the way sql checks the query pre executing..

Comment: @Michael - Is there more than one `NotificationTableLogRows` table, perhaps under a different schema?

Comment: @ScottHodgin no there isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a parse time error, not a runtime error. You can't use an `IF` check to determine if a column reference will be ok to use, because the column reference is validated first, long before the `IF` ever runs (this is why `IF 1 = 0` also fails).

> Note: The script in the question will *appear* to work (e.g. it will print `end`) if you copy the script to your own system where these *objects* do not exist. Due to deferred name resolution, the parse check will succeed if any of the *objects* do not exist yet, but will fail if all objects *do* exist, but any column does not.

As proof, compare:

```
IF 1 = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON c.blat = o.splunge;
END
GO

/* 
  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1
  Invalid column name 'blat'.
  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1
  Invalid column name 'splunge'.
*/

IF 1 = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.blats AS b
    INNER JOIN dbo.splunges AS s
    ON b.blat = s.splunge;
END
GO

/* 
  "success" 
*/
```

Now create a table called `dbo.blats` but without a column named `blat`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.blats(id int);
```

The second script still succeeds, because there is still an object that doesn't yet exist, and SQL Server is giving you the benefit of the doubt - at least at parse time - that you'll create it before you execute the script. It will fail when you add the second table, `dbo.splunges`, but without the referenced column `splunge`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.splunges(id int);
```

To get around this, you can [use this cumbersome workaround](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/13522/1186),  or just use dynamic SQL (and here I use `sys.columns` [instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, well, because](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)):

```
IF EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.columns AS c 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
      ON o.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
      ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE s.name = N'schema_name'
      AND o.name = N'object_name'
      AND c.name = N'column_name'
)
BEGIN
  EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE ... <query that references column_name> ...;';
END
```

Also [here is why I avoid shorthand metadata helpers](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions) like `OBJECT_NAME()`, `SCHEMA_NAME()`, etc., and instead recommend [creating your own helper views](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3449/making-sql-server-metadata-queries-easier-with-these-new-views/).

Comment: Thanks! The explanation rocks! I was also thinking about the EXEC, but hoped there would be another way.